# Sending e-mail with Laravel error "Class Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler does not exist"

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, smtp

I'm new Laravel 5 developer and I have an error with emails. I can't send any email through the webapp. I have tried to send an email for reset a password or receive a new user, but I can't do it. It appears the following error:

```
(1/1) ReflectionException
Class Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler does not exist

in DependencyContainer.php (line 309)
at ReflectionClass->__construct('Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler')
in DependencyContainer.php (line 309)
at Swift_DependencyContainer->_createNewInstance('transport.authhandler')
in DependencyContainer.php (line 112)...
```

The SMTP config in ".env" file is correct. I'm using Mailtrap:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=54743344954e5b
MAIL_PASSWORD=06b34d8095e637
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I don't know what's going on...

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: Thx. But it doesn't work...

Comment: Try running `rm -rf vendor/ && composer install` from your project directory

Comment: It works!!! Thank you A LOT!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I solve it the way Jonathon says. Running `rm -rf vendor/ && composer install`